# How do I use inheritance in Cheetah templates?

Tags: python, templates, inheritance, cheetah

For Cheetah3, there is a very rough documentation of the inheritance feature: http://cheetahtemplate.org/users_guide/inheritanceEtc.html#extends

But I don't get how to make it actually work.

Let's assume I have two template files:

A.tmpl

```
#def message
Hello Cheetah
#end def
This is an example: $message
```

B.tmpl

```
#extends A
#def message
Hello Cheetah with Inheritance
#end def
```

and a simple driver program such as:

```
from Cheetah.Template import Template

t = Template(file='B.tmpl')
print t
```

Obviously, that doesn't work, because there is no class A when executing this code.

But how does it go? Or is inheritance only possible with precompiled Cheetah templates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to import one template from the other.

1. Compile all templates to `*.py` files using `cheetah compile`  command line program. Then import works at the Python level.

To semi-automatically compile all templates after you edit them I recommend the following `Makefile` (GNU flavour):

```
.SUFFIXES: # Clear the suffix list
.SUFFIXES: .py .tmpl

%.py: %.tmpl
        cheetah compile --nobackup $<
        python -m compile $@

templates = $(shell echo *.tmpl)
modules = $(patsubst %.tmpl,%.py,$(templates))

.PHONY: all
all: $(modules)
```

(Don't forget — makefiles require indent with tabs, not spaces.)

2. Subvert Python import to make Cheetah import directly from `*.tmpl` files.

Code:

```
from Cheetah import ImportHooks
ImportHooks.install()

import sys
sys.path.insert(0, 'path/to/template_dir')  # or sys.path.append
```

PS. ImportHooks automatically try to import from `*.pyc`, `*.py` and `*.tmpl` — whatever is found first. A few days ago I extended ImportHooks to automatically compile `*.tmpl` to `*.py` and `*.pyc`. I'm going to write more docs and push in a few days. Expect the final release Cheetah 3.2 in a few months.

Comment: Ok, cool, thanks for your answer, phd. When I add the lines `from Cheetah import ImportHooks` and `ImportHooks.install()`to my example above, it works. Great!